# Git Bash(Guest OS) and GitBash(Host OS) show different status

Tags: git, virtual-machine, samba

Little bit of intro.

I have a repository on my guest(VirtualBox) Ubuntu OS. I usually access it via Putty SSH terminal. From that terminal I ca run "git status" and see that the working directory is clean.

But. I want to use my GUI Git Extensions from the Host Win10 machine. Because the Ubuntu is GUIless. So I shared folder using [Samba](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/install-and-configure-samba#1). Now I can use my code editor as well as other GUI apps like Git Extensions. But the problem is that the Git on Host and Git on Guest are showing different status, when ran on the same directory. Please see the examples below.

Git Bash(Guest) and git extensions (or GitBash on host) show different status.

Git extension (Host OS):

```
- Git Extensions 3.00.00.4433
- Build fca7cf228b481ee8c1b779cf7b882ccdfbdcd1bc
- Git 2.20.1.windows.1
- Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.17763.0
- .NET Framework 4.7.3324.0
- DPI 96dpi (no scaling)
```

Git bash(guest OS):

```
git version 2.7.4
```

And totally different working directory state:

[image]

Greyed one is the GitExtensions console and the light-blue one is the git bash(on Guest Ubunty(GUIless)).

Running GitBash for the same repository, but from the HOST OS give the same result:

[image]

Can someone explain me where this difference come from?

Comment: Are you sure that the `git status` command is supported by git-extensions? I can't find its documentation. Maybe it's just not supported.

Comment: It is the built in console Extensions uses. I guess it uses the default system git bash console

Comment: Are these outputs of the *same* repo? Or is one on a VM and the other on the host machine?

Comment: It doesn't look like you ran `git status` in the same repo.

Technically speaking the output of a command run in a console has nothing to do with GE itself - you ran a git command and received an output. 
We just host a console so the users don't need to switch to a different window. 

In the UI (e.g. the revision graph or the left panel) GE only shows what it received from git.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. I added a little bit of intro  in the original post in order to give some background. Probably this will give more information to think.

Comment: Perhaps an autocrlf issue? I prefer to completely disable line ending conversion. What is shown by git diff?

Comment: @Marcus, Yes you are right. Please see my comment below the first answer.

Answer (score 0):

First things first: It is never a good idea to "share local access" to a repo as you are doing.  If you need to use a repo in multiple environments, you should clone it in each environment.

Since you're sharing across different OS's, there is the potential for each to interpret the status of the working directory differently.  (For example, it could have to do with line endings - which I think is most likely - or filename capitalization - which I think is less likely.)

You might be able to configure around those differences; or you can remove the underlying problem (and avoid other potential pitfalls) by using the mechanisms built in to git for sharing a repo between environments.

Comment: Yes I see it is about the line endings. I don't use the Windows git for other reasons but to monitor using GUI as Git Extensions. No commits no pushes nothing at all. Just watching graphs and differences between commits and working directory. But the problem arises ONLY when I want to see the difference between the HEAD and working directory. It shows everything is changed, whilst it is not. I just want to make the HOST(Win10) git ignore differences in line ending characters, so I can can use the GUI. Again, just for watching.

Comment: My first thought was also to recommend not to use one repo in multiple environments, but then I realized I am doing this every day - because I use git bash and Eclipse egit in parallel accessing the very same repository. This is nothing really different. And it works - regarding only the git part of the problem - very well.

Comment: @Marcus - No, that is not at all the same

Comment: Tell me why ?!?

Comment: @Marcus - I'd check your attitude if you want help from people online.  As for why, let's start with: how many different OS's do you have accessing that repo instance?

Comment: Sorry just tried to help. Didn't know this isn't appreciated.